# use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement

Tags: maven

I am trying to do maven install on my project. its failing and giving me this exception

```
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Also its giving me below error

```
[ERROR] /F:/Automation_June_2022/QA-Tech-Automation/src/main/java/com/bddframework/StepDefinitions/crm/UpdateMSKU.java:[50,41] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
[ERROR] /F:/Automation_June_2022/QA-Tech-Automation/src/main/java/com/bddframework/StepDefinitions/GuestUserLoginWithPromoFromShoppingCart.java:[46,41] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this error?

After doing Maven install

```
[ERROR] /F:/Automation_June_2022/QA-Tech-Automation/src/main/java/com/bddframework/StepDefinitions/crm/UpdateMSKU.java:[50,41] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
[ERROR] /F:/Automation_June_2022/QA-Tech-Automation/src/main/java/com/bddframework/StepDefinitions/GuestUserLoginWithPromoFromShoppingCart.java:[46,41] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

This is under Effective POM; we can't edit Maven compile version file

Comment: What is the output of `mvn -v`

Comment: @seenukarthi irrelevant, the problem is the target version for the compiler

Comment: @jwenting It is relevant if the java version used in maven is less than 1.7 the `-source 7` cannot be used. OP didn't mention any information about maven version or java version thus I asked for the output of `mvn -v`

Comment: @seenukarthi had the compiler not known about the existence of multi-catch statements it would simply have thrown a syntax error :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't tell Maven to compile to a language specification of 1.7 or higher, don't use language features newer than 1.6 in your code.

It's really that simple. Got to wonder though what environment you are in if you are stuck with a 1.6 or order JDK. It's definitely not a professional environment, or any serious educational establishment as those should follow what's commonly used in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the `source` and `target` versions in maven by adding the following properties in your pom.

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Note: For this to work your Java version should be 1.7 or later.